# Jmeter - Scheduler is not working

Tags: jmeter

I have 2 questions related to Thread Group Scheduler.
Here is my Test Plan

> ```
> >Test Plan  
> >> Transaction Controller
> >>> Login.jsp  
> >>> Home.jsp  
> >>> Something.jsp
> >Cookie Manager
> >Cache Manager
> >Listner
> ```

Thread Group with Scheduler -

```
Number of Threads = 30000
Ramp up time = 500
Loop = 1

Start Time = 2014/08/04 13:00:00
End Time = 2014/08/04 15:00:00
Duration (seconds) = Blank
Startup delay (seconds) = Blank
```

1. When I set start time and end time as mentioned above it starts properly on given time but as soon as all 30000 threads executes it stops the script and I finds 30000 session in tomcat with 0.1 or 1 second used time(and remain Idle for rest of the time) then what is significance of End time, as I explored everyone says it will execute till the end time.
2. If it will execute till the end time then all 30000 sessions in Tomcat will be active(Idle time = 00) till end time currently it shows used time only 1 or less second, and rest is Idle time.

Please Help me..

Thanks in Advance

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't made extensive use of the thread group scheduler yet, but have had my own fun with throughput and timers.

Your loop is set to "1", should it not be set to "-1" so that loops does not limit the total working time or throughput?

Comment: The Loop count is not "-1", Mode correction in question.

Comment: BTW should I use "Forever" Loop?

Comment: If you set loops to -1 then it will loop forever, the same as selecting the "Loop Forever" option. I use -1 simply because we use an external load testing service.

Edit: You should try setting loops to forever and let us know the results.

Comment: When I set Loop count forever and schedule my test for 3 hours with 30k it shows 99% error.... Although I used think timer(random with 1 sec as constant and 1 sec offset) in the script.

Comment: How are you generating 30,000 threads? We found that on a reasonably powerful computer (quad core, 16gb ram) we could only generate about 550-700 threads then it maxes out. This was with a 3-8 second wait time per page.

Comment: We have 56GB Ram, Xenon or some thing processor and I have allocated 30 gb ram for Java, I have given Rampup as 2000 secs in Thread group.

Comment: I think you are limited by threads depending on how many cores your processor has.

Open an aggregate sampler of some sort and analyse the number of hits you are producing per minute compared to what you expect. I think you will find a large discrepancy.